# How to create multi index dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas

How to create multi index data [image]frames in pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First option

One of possibe solutions is to create the MultiIndex **from tuples**:

Start from defining source tuples:

```
tpl = [('', 'Material'), ('', 'Brand'),
    ('abcd.com', 'Stock'), ('abcd.com', 'Sales'), ('abcd.com', 'Leftover'),
    ('xyz.com',  'Stock'), ('xyz.com',  'Sales'), ('xyz.com', 'Leftover')]
```

Each tuple contains respective column name at consecutive levels.

Then create the MultiIndex:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tpl)
```

And now you can create your DataFrame, calling e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(<your_data>, columns=cols)
```

## Another option

The second choice is to create the MultiIndex **from arrays**:

Source data is actually a **list** containing column names (also **lists**) for each level:

```
arr = [[ '', '', 'abcd.com', 'abcd.com', 'abcd.com', 'xyz.com', 'xyz.com', 'xyz.com' ],
       [ 'Material', 'Brand', 'Stock', 'Sales', 'Leftover', 'Stock', 'Sales', 'Leftover']]
```

Then, to create the MultiIndex, call:

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arr)
```